# Infobip SMS bulk messages API with flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, api, dart, infobip

My post request doesn't work

I've tried running this but i end up with :

```
{"requestError":{"serviceException":{"messageId":"UNAUTHORIZED","text":"Invalid logindetails"}}}
```

This is my code :

```
data() async { 

final client = HttpClient();

final request = await client .postUrl(Uri.parse("https://....api.infobip.com/sms/2/text/advanced")); request.headers.set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, "{'Authorization':'App ...KEY','Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'}");

request.write({ '"messages": [{"from": "sms","destinations": [{"to": "..."}],"text": "ABC"}]' });

final response = await request.close();

response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) {
 print(contents); 
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out an answer for this `POST` request in flutter

```
makePostRequest(int number) async {
  final uri = Uri.parse('https://....api.infobip.com/sms/2/text/advanced');
  final headers = {
    'Authorization':
        'App API-KEY',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };
  Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    "messages": [
      {
        "from": "SenderID",
        "destinations": [
          {"to": number}
        ],
        "text": "TEST!"
      }
    ]
  };

  String jsonBody = json.encode(body);
  final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');

  Response response = await post(
    uri,
    headers: headers,
    body: jsonBody,
    encoding: encoding,
  );

  int statusCode = response.statusCode;
  String responseBody = response.body;
  print(responseBody);
}
```